# Ubuntu 18.04.5 Shutdown taking too much time (90+ seconds)

Tags: shutdown, laptop

I am using ubuntu 18.04.5. When I shut down my laptop it takes too much time in my sense. So I tried this [method](https://itsfoss.com/long-shutdown-linux/) to quick shutdown, it worked fine and my laptop shut down almost immediately. Now my question is, Is there any bad impact of this method on my PC's hardware resource?

Comment: You can diagnose the shutdown problem. First, get a clean "too much time" shutdown. Issue your shutdown, then wait (up to 45 minutes, probably 30 minutes) for your laptop to shutdown. Reboot, then, in a terminal window `sudo journalctl  -b -1 -e` to see the previous boot's log's last page. Look for."`timeout`" messages, or timestamps with large intervals between them.

Comment: Hereby "too much time" I mean taking 90 to 120 second of time. but when I tried the method I mentioned above, My laptop shut down almost instantly(2 or 3 sec). So I am curious about the fact that is there any bad effect of this method of the quick shutdown. @waltinator

Answer (score 0):

The default timeouts of systemd are completely insane; typically it's 30 seconds, and they tend to add up. Check your current settings with:

```
grep -i timeout /etc/systemd/*.conf
```

Then make a decision if there is anything that could possibly really take 30 seconds to shut down, or if you want to reduce e.g. `DefaultTimeoutStopSec` to something more reasonable like 10 or even 5 seconds.

IMHO any process that isn't finished shutting down itself within 5 seconds is seriously broken by design.

Comment: /etc/systemd/logind.conf:#HoldoffTimeoutSec=30s
after runnng the command you mentioned I found this, /etc/systemd/system.conf:#DefaultTimeoutStartSec=90s
/etc/systemd/system.conf:DefaultTimeoutStopSec=10s
/etc/systemd/user.conf:#DefaultTimeoutStartSec=90s
/etc/systemd/user.conf:#DefaultTimeoutStopSec=90s